# I am new with Ruby and Cucumber and I got this error undefined method `col_span' for class `Watir::TableCell' (NameError) what should I do?

Tags: cucumber, ruby

I am new with Ruby and Cucumber and I got this error:

> undefined method 'col_span' for class 'Watir::TableCell' (NameError)

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: First link on Google when I copy&paste your error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404716/undefined-method-col-span-for-class-watirtablecell-nameerror Does that solve your problem?

Comment: It looks like there is an issue with the Watir ruby gem itself which maybe throwing the error. Can you please share the details of ruby version used, watir gem version and your os details. Also please share the script.